# Change Google Maps' RichMarker cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

### Explanation

For some reason, when using [RichMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker) (so I can use Font Awesome's fonts), it isn't allowed to change the cursor. As you can see below, when hovering Google Maps' marker, the cursor changes as the code says, but nothing happens with RichMarker's. Am I doing anything wrong?

### Code

You can also see it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uucdjx9/).

```js
function initialize() {
    var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.773293, -122.469468);
    var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.774548, -122.467054);
    
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatLng1
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    
    // First Marker
    var marker = new RichMarker({
        position: myLatLng1,
        map: map,
        flat:true,
        content: '<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-4x"></i>',
        cursor: 'default'
    });
    
    // Second Marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng2,
        map: map,
        cursor: 'default'
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker/gh-pages/src/richmarker.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: because in RichMarker example he use `draggable: true`, code in `richmarker.js` find the line `Sets the cursor` u will see he wrote `if (whichCursor == 'draggable') {
      cursor = 'pointer';
    }` . u need change your logic code in your `richmarker.js`

Comment: Thank you!! As I don't want it do be draggable, I all had to do was to delete those if statements regarding it and set `var cursor = 'pointer';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Hua Trung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4177526/hua-trung) in the comments above, I needed to change [richmarker.js](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker/blob/gh-pages/src/richmarker.js).

Since I didn't want the marker to be draggable, I could delete everything about it.

So I:

- looked for `Sets the cursor` (line 428);
- deleted everything from line 439 to line 460;
- changed `var cursor = '';` (line 438) to `var cursor = 'pointer';` (or the cursor of your preference).

It's now as follows (from line 427).

```
/**
 * Sets the cursor.
 *
 * @param {string} whichCursor What cursor to show.
 * @private
 */
RichMarker.prototype.setCursor_ = function(whichCursor) {
  if (!this.ready_) {
    return;
  }

  var cursor = 'pointer';

  if (this.markerWrapper_.style.cursor != cursor) {
    this.markerWrapper_.style.cursor = cursor;
  }
};
```